# How to convert a mesh with vertex colors to grease pencil and keep the vertex colors?

Tags: mesh, grease-pencil, vertex-colors

I have a Mesh that has Vertex Colors. Is there a way to convert the coloured mesh to grease pencil, and keep the Vertex Colors? Right now, when I convert it, the lines only become black.

I am using Blender 2.93

Thanks in advance for help!